# Kafka Broker throws SchemaException: Error reading field 'topics (with Kafka-Manager)

Tags: apache-kafka, yahoo-kafka-manager

I am getting the following exception while using Kafka-manager(1.3.1.*) with Kafka(0.8.2.1) cluster.

```
ERROR Closing socket for /XX.XX.XX.XX because of error (kafka.network.Processor)
org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.SchemaException: Error reading field 'topics': java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
        at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.Schema.read(Schema.java:66)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.JoinGroupRequest.parse(JoinGroupRequest.java:85)
        at kafka.api.JoinGroupRequestAndHeader$.readFrom(JoinGroupRequestAndHeader.scala:29)
        at kafka.api.RequestKeys$$anonfun$12.apply(RequestKeys.scala:50)
        at kafka.api.RequestKeys$$anonfun$12.apply(RequestKeys.scala:50)
        at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.<init>(RequestChannel.scala:50)
        at kafka.network.Processor.read(SocketServer.scala:450)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:340)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:74
```

By looking at the exception,It can be inferred that there is version mismatch between kafka-manager and broker.

In Kafka-Manager UI, I gave the version similar to the version of broker still I am getting this.

I also found that the kafka-manager is using org.apache.kafka.kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar,org..apache.kafka.kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1.jar.

So,How to fix this issue? Is there any parameter in kafka-manager to specify the version of kafka boker or It is a bug ?